# Pause a Vzaar Video in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, video

Video in a Bootsrap modal continues to play when the modal is closed.
I have found solutions for YouTube video and html5 video but i am using Vzaar Video and Vzaar's API java script

I have it working from the close button in the modal (using id="video-btn") but I really need it to work also if clicking outside of the modal, or I guess on data-dismiss="modal", which should cover all (?).

Not being great with java, help would be appreciated.
My code just for the close button (which works fine) is below.

```
// Vzaar
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
var player = new vzPlayer("vzvd-XXXXXXX");

// adding pause() API method to DOM element:
var myPauseButton = document.getElementById("video-btn");
myPauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.pause();
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it:

```
// add listener vzaar video //

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
var player = new vzPlayer("vzvd-xxxxxxx");

// adding pause() API method to hidden.bs.modal: //

$('#myModalId').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
player.pause();
  }); 
});
```

(of course http://player.vzaar.com/libs/flashtakt/client.js needs to be included)